# 403 Forbidden when Non-Admin attempts to upload a file

Tags: 403

I am uploading doucment using object model. However my 'UploadFile()' method throws exception "The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.".
This happens if my current user is not a member of one custom group (ABCGroup). And 'ABCGroup' has all permissions. Even if I give 'Full Control' permissions to this user it doesn't work. So I am really wondering.

Comment: It's happening when they are part of ABCGroup or are not part of ABCGroup? It would be helpful to post a bit more code - there are some API calls that require high permissions.

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to upload  files through code, did you try to use the 
RunWithElevatedPrivileges method ? Below is a link which will give you more information on the method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb466220(office.12).aspx

You can do something like this:

```
SPSite siteColl = SPContext.Current.Site;
SPWeb site = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() {
using (SPSite ElevatedsiteColl = new SPSite(siteColl.ID)) {
 using (SPWeb ElevatedSite = ElevatedsiteColl.OpenWeb(site.ID)) {

    ////Add your code to upload the file  here....

 }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are adding the document through the `UploadFile()` method to a document library. So make sure the user who is uploading the document has permission to the document library. No need to use `RunWithElevatedPrivileges`.